# webview occupies the complete screen in android application

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview in my layout. This webview occupies only a part of the screen. But when I load the webview with a url it occupies the complete screen. I just want to show the webpage in a particular part of the screen.

If I do not load the webview with a url it displays correctly as I expected. It fills the screen only when I load it with a url. Below is my code.

```
  <WebView  
android:id="@+id/webView"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"  />

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Are you using your own `WebViewClient`?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `WebView` inside a `LinearLayout`/`RelativeLayout` and specify the height and width of the Layout. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="100dp"
 android:layout_height="200dp"
 --other properties>
   <WebView  
   android:id="@+id/webView"
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="200dp"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. But its not working. My webview is in a relative layout and I'm using a textview which has the same property as the webview and this textview works really fine. Also the webview fills the screen only when I load the webview with a URl. Otherwise it displays correctly.

Comment: Then wrap the webView inside RelativeLayout and specify the height/width attribute